# Vercel with AWS not working: "Deploy failed, and no monitoring URL was given"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, next.js, vercel

My application is written with next.js and the pipeline is:

```
> Github PR
  > AWS builds BE/FE application
    > Build assets are piped up to vercel.com for FE hosting.
```

Currently, the FE builds successfully, but the stumbling block is talking with vercel it seems. I am rather stuck now, having had this working 6 months ago.

Google has no results:
[image]

### AWS Log

```
2021-06-06T22:39:17.230Z [INFO]: # Executing command: if [ "packages" == "master" ]; then ./now-deploy.sh --prod --scope teamXXX; fi
                                 # Executing command: if [ "packages" != "master" ]; then ./now-deploy.sh --scope teamXXX; fi
2021-06-06T22:39:17.286Z [INFO]: [now-deploy 2021-06-06 22:39:17] Attempting preview deployment
2021-06-06T22:39:17.287Z [INFO]: [now-deploy 2021-06-06 22:39:17] Deployment command: now deploy -d -C -c -f --scope=teamXXX --token=<<REDACTED>>
2021-06-06T22:39:22.768Z [INFO]: [now-deploy 2021-06-06 22:39:22] Deploy failed, and no monitoring URL was given (see https://vercel.com/ for details)
2021-06-06T22:39:22.771Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-06-06T22:39:22.771Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2021-06-06T22:39:22.771Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-06-06T22:39:22.771Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2021-06-06T22:39:22.847Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

In short, I am failing now to know where to look to find where this failure might be happening.

Comment: I would recommend that you use `vercel` instead of `now`. The `now` package is deprecated.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the answer! @paulogdm it is? Isn't it Amazons built in whoopey-de-do? Or thinking about it... `now` is part of vercel?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply that the access token created through https://vercel.com/account/tokens was out of date, the error on AWS does not make this clear.

I created a new token on vercel and updated it on AWS Amplify `Environment variable` name: `VERCEL_TOKEN` [image]